# How to prevent empty XML elements in XSD, and validate using JAXB?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

**Why is the `minLength` constraint not enforced in Java generated by JAXB during unmarshalling?**

I have the following element

```
<subHeader seqno="1"><![CDATA[sub header1]]></subHeader>
```

and I would like my XSD to prevent empty elements, such as this

```
<subHeader seqno="2" />
```

Current XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="subHeader" type="subHeaderType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
</xsd:element> 
<xsd:complexType name="subHeaderType">
   <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="NotEmpty">
         <xsd:attribute name="seqno" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
      </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType> 

<xsd:simpleType name="NotEmpty">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:minLength value="1"></xsd:minLength>
      <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"></xsd:whiteSpace>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSD would allow

```
<subHeader seqno="1"><![CDATA[sub header1]]></subHeader>
```

because it is ***not empty*** but prevent

```
<subHeader seqno="2" />
```

because it is ***empty***.

*Therefore, your XSD already meets your requirements as is.*

---

**Update**: OP in comments mentions that the query is really about the **`xsd:minLength` constraint not being represented in JAXB during unmarshalling**.

To enable validation per your XSD, set an instance of `Schema` on your `Unmarshaller`.  Here's an example of doing so and handling validation events via `ValidationEventHandler`:

```
package blog.jaxb.validation;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

public class MyValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("\nEVENT");
        System.out.println("SEVERITY:  " + event.getSeverity());
        System.out.println("MESSAGE:  " + event.getMessage());
        System.out.println("LINKED EXCEPTION:  " + event.getLinkedException());
        System.out.println("LOCATOR");
        System.out.println("    LINE NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
        System.out.println("    COLUMN NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
        System.out.println("    OFFSET:  " + event.getLocator().getOffset());
        System.out.println("    OBJECT:  " + event.getLocator().getObject());
        System.out.println("    NODE:  " + event.getLocator().getNode());
        System.out.println("    URL:  " + event.getLocator().getURL());
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Code credit**: [Blaise Doughan's blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html), an outstanding JAXB resource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But after unmarshall the xml,  Still i could see seqno=2 attribute in jaxb-xjc bean, and i dont see any generated code for 'minLength' constraint/restriction, my expected output after unmarshall object.getSuHeader() should have only seqno=1 data, not seqno=2, Pls help me out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, For your understanding I'm generating jaxb-xjc beans from xsd to unmarshall, But after unmarshall the xml,  Still i could see seqno=2 attribute in jaxb-xjc bean, and i dont see any generated code for 'minLength' constraint/restriction, my expected output after unmarshall object.getSuHeader() should have only seqno=1 data, not seqno=2, Pls help me out.

Comment: Then you really should have mentioned that your ***question is essentially about JAXB*** in your question originally.   Answer updated.  Question updated.  Thanks.